# encounter a bug when print data in R

Tags: r

I have a data https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyauarlvaynsra4/may_be_a_bug.rds?dl=0. You can read with `readRDS`. This file has 300 entries. However, if you print it, it will show the 301th number. (I checked, it skip number 262 (I don't why it's this number) If I convert it to array, then the problem gone. This is just a visual problem, everything else is correct. (length is correct)

This is a very weird bug which I probably described poorly. This may not be the best place to post this. But I don't where I should report this to.(R doesn't seem to have a github repo) I hope someone with more experience can help to solve this or explain what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug at all. When you print the data, the number in the left column is actually the row name, not the row index. Most likely row 262 was deleted previously. You can rename the row names if you like, I will only show the last few entries for clarity:

```
m=readRDS("may_be_a_bug.rds")
print(m)

297 -0.776732190
298 -0.853759107
299 -1.447553778
300  0.315203217
301 -0.804833647

row.names(m)=1:nrow(m)
print(m)

296 -0.776732190
297 -0.853759107
298 -1.447553778
299  0.315203217
300 -0.804833647
```

Comment: you are right. I didn't think it as label before. I got the data from a package(SAheart from ElemStatLearn). It misses the 262th data at the beginning.

Comment: Happy to help :)